# Unable to setup mysql in google cloud shell

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to install mysql in a cloud engine through the cloud shell

I installed it with:

```
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

And set password with:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

when I input the password, I receive this error:

```
Enter current password for root (enter for none):
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you realize that only software that you install in your home directory will persist? Cloud Shell is a container. When the container is restarted your MySQL instance will disappear. I don't have an answer as Cloud does not support what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John say, Cloud shell is a container.

You should use cloud shell to login to your vm

For example, your VM name is mysql-server

```
gcloud compute ssh username@mysql-server
```

Then follow with your install setup.

Or

```
gcloud compute ssh username@mysql-server --command 'sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server'
```